# incrementing integer value stored as tcl string

Tags: string, tcl

I have to implement a feature in which i have a file name and that name contains some integer value in the end and i want to increment that integer value by one. To be more clear, the problem string "filename" is :

> asdfasdfasdfa.foo.old001

now i have to check if this file name exists, and if it does i have to name my new file to

> asdfasdfasdfa.foo.old002

and so on. I can think of one solution which is to get the last string ".old001" using

> file extension string

command and then using regular expression get the last three characters and add '1' to it and then join the file name to this new extension. But i am not sure if it is a good and optimal solution. Any other ideas or help would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
proc incr_filename {name} {
    set digits [regexp -inline {\d+$} $name]
    set prefix [string range $name 0 end-[string length $digits]]
    set num [scan $digits %d]  ;# prevents problems with invalid octal numbers 
    format "%s%0*d" $prefix [string length $digits] [incr num]
}

puts [incr_filename asdfasdfasdfa.foo.old001]
```

And to find the non-existant filename:

```
set filename abcd.ext.old001
while {[file exists $filename]} {
    set filename [incr_filename $filename]
}
puts "new filename is $filename"
```

Comment: If using `regexp` anyway, why not capture the prefix, _i.e._ use `set matches [regexp -inline {(.*?)(\d+)$} $name]`?